# Reliability model

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, reliability

What follows is an illustration of a problem that I am facing in real life.
A fabric mades toy and for the delivery there are three different processes:

1. Process A: reception of the pieces.
2. Process B: mount of a battery on a piece.
3. Process C: glue all the pieces together.

After each process, the pieces are inspected and a probability that a toy is defective can be calculated. Let us note the probability that a toy is defective after process A,B and C $P_A,P_B$ and $P_C$ respectively. At each step of the process, the way to calculate $P_A,P_B,P_C$ might be different. The probability $P_B$ is computed from the pieces (data) coming from the process $A$ and the probability $P_C$ is calculated from the pieces (data) coming from process $B$, and, so from process $A$ too.

The goal is to find the probability $P$ that a toy is defective at the end of the process.

Here is what I have read and with which I do not agree:
$$
P = \min(P_A,P_B,P_C) \ \ \ (1).
$$

Defining the overall probability $P$ as in equation (1) is equivalent to say that each $P_A$, $P_B$ and $P_C$ are independent of each other and do not affect each other. However this can not be the case since the determination of $P_A,P_B,P_C$ comes from the same toys, just at different step of the process. To be more precise, I would say that
$$
P = P_C \ \ (2).
$$

Everything can happen between two processes and some toy could be broken before arriving at the end.

To illustrate why I do not agree with equation (1), let us think about the following example:

$P_A = 0.05$, $P_B = 0.1$ and $P_C = 0.2$. Then we have $P = 0.05$. But his does not take into account that the pieces will go through B and C.

Moreover, $P_B$ does not represent the probability of finding defective toys after going through process $B$ but represents the probability of finding defective toys after going through processes A and B. Same reasoning for $P_C$

For me, the inspections between each processes are then useless, and only the final inspection is important.
Any advice, critics about my reasoning are welcome.

Comment: You have defined $P_A$ etc as probability of being **defective** , $P_A$ = 0.999 ????

Comment: Sorry, it is just an example and it is not a good number. I will change it.

Comment: In a shotgun type process, using the highest defect rate at any point to compute reliability seems natural, no ?

Comment: The reliability is not the *defect rate*, if $P_A$ is the highest defect rate in a straight line process, reliability would be $1- P_A\;$ I think the idea is that tbey are screening for different *types* of defects at different points.

Comment: So if an inspection after process C gives a defect rate of 5% and after process A a defect rate of 10%, then choosing 10% would be overestimating the defect rate. This is because an inspection can give you with a certain confidence level the defect rate after C.

Comment: This is min and not max, I changed it in the question after having read your first comment.

Comment: What you say seems right based on how you introduced the probabilities. Either the text you read is wrong, or your reproduction of it is wrong. We can't tell which it is unless you quote the text verbatim.

Comment: Thanks joriki for your answer. It is not from a text but from reality. I am reviewing what it is already done and try to understand it. Thanks :).